# Select2 - create an autocomplete select box from 15k cells array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I'm using [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple-max) in order to create styled select boxes with autocomplete. I have 2 choices, load the data from a `json` file, or create a simple `array` from that `json` and use a workaround to populate the `select` tag. I read through their api examples but obviously I'm missing something. My goal is to create a drop down list with many elements, the problem is that the data is a huge array, which consists of aprox **15k** cells. I tried a workaround using this code:

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select item" id="itemsList">
```

JS:

```
var list = $("#itemsList");
var txt = "";
for(var i=0;i<itemsArray.length;i++){
   txt =txt+ '<option value='+itemsArray[i]+'>'+itemsArray[i]+'</option>';
   }
list.append(txt);
```

This works, but obviously `select2` manages things more efficiently, as this "method" takes several good seconds to load the data in to the `DOM`.

The second approach is to load the `json` straight to the `select2` box and let the framework to manage the construction, but this leads me to an error: `Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`.
[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/btwdr80g/)

This is the code:
HTML:

```
<div class="input-group" id="itemContainer"> 
    <label> Select an item: </label>
    <select multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Items list" id="itemList"> 
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $("select").select2({
      ajax: {
        //this is a small demo json to illustrate its structure
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/5amne",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 0,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            console.log(data);
          params.page = params.page || 1;

          return {
            results: data.items,
            pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            }
          };
        },
        cache: true
      },
      escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
      minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```

Comment: Loading that much data in to the DOM is always going to be slow. I would suggest you look in to using an autocomplete instead, so the users can search for only the entries they need instead of dumping them all to the client regardless.

Comment: That means I would need to create another, sub-array of items at the moment the user enters the first letter. Wouldn't that take a while too? Searching through 15k cells doesn't sound like a quick task.

Comment: It would depend on how you're storing the data. If it's in a database it would be a trivial task. It would also have the benefit of massively reducing bandwidth.

Comment: The data is loaded from a local `json` file, no server\db involved.

Comment: What is the format of data in your JSON file?

Comment: @Dethariel please look here: https://api.myjson.com/bins/5amne

Comment: Then your format is incorrect, like stated by Z. Alpha. You're setting `results: data.items,`, but the `items` property is missing in JSON you reference. What is the expected output for that JSON?

Comment: @Dethariel you can think of this `json` as a representation of a country, and all cities in that country, for every country. So I dont have a specific `key`. In my "real world" app, there are two `select` boxes, one for the `item_x`, and the second `select` is for its sub-contents `item_x_optionx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `processData` function should handle custom data format, e.g. parse it in a way that is understandable by the select2. Here's how it can be done:

```
processResults: function (data) {
    var results = $.map(data, function (value, key) {
        return {
            text: key,
            children: $.map(value, function (v) {
                return {
                    id: v,
                    text: v
                };
            })
        };
    });

    return {
        results: results,
    };
},
```

See the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btwdr80g/1/)

#### Edit

If you want the select2 to handle filtering for you, there are two ways of doing that:

1. Adding server-side support;
2. Handling everything on the client.

Since you're loading data via from a static JSON file, you need to go #2. In order to do that, you first need to load all the data, parse it, and only then initialize the select2 control. You can do it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/btwdr80g/2/):

```
function processData(data) {
    return $.map(data, function (value, key) {
        return {
            text: key,
            children: $.map(value, function (v) {
                return {
                    id: key + v,
                    text: v
                };
            })
        };
    });
}

function initSelect2(data) {
    $("select").select2({
        data: data
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1n1rm",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: true,
    success: function (data) {
        initSelect2(processData(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is almost perfect. Several questions: 1. Is it possible to show only relevant results? Now it shows everything regardless to what is entered in the box.
2. Do you think this solution will work well with huge `json` with thousands of lines?

Comment: Updated my answer for 1. Regarding the speed - you won't know unless you try. But in order for things to be quicker, the first thing you need to do is to format your `*.json` file to be in compliance with what select2 expects, so that you don't have to parse the response on the client-side

Comment: To combat the speed issues, you can improve the speed by reducing the number of options which are matched. The easiest way to do that is by using `minimumInputLength`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use json for select2, the json format should be something like this:

```
{ results: [ {id:'first', text:'a'}, {id:'second', text: 'b'} ]
  , more: false }
```

[JSON format for jquery-select2 multi with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598549/json-format-for-jquery-select2-multi-with-ajax)

Your current json doesn't seem to have the right format. I think you should change your json format.