# Select2 Ajax inquiry not retrieving results

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, jquery-select2

I am using select2 and ajax to query my database for terms under a certain taxonomy, but when I search the search boxes just hangs on "searching" without retrieving any results.

**This is my html**

```
<select multiple="" name="regions1[]" id="regions1" class="job-manager-multiselect select2-hidden-accessible" required="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
```

**My jquery:**

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#regions1" ).select2({        
ajax: {
    url: "/ajax/connect.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            q: params.term // search term
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data
        return {
            results: data
        };
    },
    cache: true
},
minimumInputLength: 2
  });
  });
   });
 </script>
```

and my php code to query the database, **I am looking to get all the term names under the taxonomy "job_listing_region"**

```
<?php

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "myusername";
  $password = "mypassword";

   try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydatabase", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   }
    catch(PDOException $e)
   {
   echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
   }



  // strip tags may not be the best method for your project to apply extra 
   layer of security but fits needs for this tutorial 
   $search = strip_tags(trim($_GET['q'])); 

 // Do Prepared Query
   $query = $conn->prepare("
   SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT wp_terms.name
   FROM wp_terms
   JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
    ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
    WHERE taxonomy = 'job_listing_region'
    AND count = 0
    ) as T"
     );

    // Add a wildcard search to the search variable
     $query->execute(array(':search'=>"%".$search."%"));


   // Do a quick fetchall on the results
    $list = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   // Make sure we have a result
   if(count($list) > 0){
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array('id' => $value['name'], 'text' => $value['name']);              
   } 
    } else {
   $data[] = array('id' => '0', 'text' => 'No Products Found');
   }


// return the result in json
echo json_encode($data);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$query = $smnt->prepare(...` I don't see `$smnt` defined anywhere. I'd bet you're getting PHP errors, and your server is reporting them as 404's. Try hitting `/ajax/connect.php` in your browser with PHP errors turned on to debug.

Comment: @mopo922 you were right, i got "syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) wp-content/ajax/connect.php on line 33, any suggestions?

Comment: `try` should always be followed by a `catch` block - see [this doc](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for valid try/catch implementation

Comment: And you should use `$conn->prepare` instead of `$smnt->prepare`

Comment: @vard thanks, I am now able to see all the terms when i hit ajax/connect.php, e.g "{"id":"Abanda, AL","text":"Abanda, AL"}", but when i search abanda, al in the select2 box I am still receiving a "...ajax/connect.php?q=abanda 404 (Not Found)" error

Comment: When you look at the URL from the console, is it the exact same as the one you have in your browser? Because it seems like the path is invalid.

Comment: @vard the url was off, that fixed the 404, but now the select2 boxs just hangs on "searching" without retrieving any results or throwing any errors, not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It's probably because you're not returning valid JSON for select2 - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598549/json-format-for-jquery-select2-multi-with-ajax) - it show how JSON data should be structured for select2.

Comment: You're binding the `:search` parameter to the query, but the query doesn't include that parameter. I think that's your problem

Comment: @vard I believe my data is structured correctly all results display as [{"id":"Abanda, AL","text":"Abanda, AL"} .

Comment: @alon, I tried removing `:search` from the  array, but still no luck.

Comment: I don't know much about select2, but it seems the JSON should be formatted in this way: `{results: [...], more: false }`, and then in your `processResults` function change to `results: data.results`. Maybe select2 expect this `more` attribute at some other level. Isn't there any error message in your browser console about that?

Comment: @vard I will try playing around with the format, but no there is no error message, which is very odd as nothing is being returned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 ajax not showing results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640368/select2-ajax-not-showing-results)